# ABPeoplePickerNavigationController + predicateWithBlock | crash

Tags: ios, objective-c

I got my own PeoplePicker Controller which inherts from `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController`. I am trying to set a `NSPredicate` for `self.predicateForEnablingPerson` using `preidcateWithBlock` like this:

```
self.predicateForEnablingPerson = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        return YES;
    }];
```

and it crashes with the error:

> ** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'NSBlockPredicate cannot be encoded or decoded'

```
*** First throw call stack:  
(  
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ea3fc65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165  
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010e615bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45  
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ea3fb9d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205  
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010c7e5974 -[NSXPCEncoder _encodeObject:] + 628  
    4   Foundation                          0x000000010c7f452c -[NSXPCEncoder _encodeArrayOfObjects:forKey:] + 276  
    5   Foundation                          0x000000010c7ce55c -[NSDictionary(NSDictionary) encodeWithCoder:] + 904  
    6   Foundation                          0x000000010c7e5974 -[NSXPCEncoder _encodeObject:] + 628  
    7   Foundation                          0x000000010c7f452c -[NSXPCEncoder _encodeArrayOfObjects:forKey:] + 276  
    8   Foundation                          0x000000010c7ce55c -[NSDictionary(NSDictionary) encodeWithCoder:] + 904  
    9   Foundation                          0x000000010c7e5974 -[NSXPCEncoder _encodeObject:] + 628  
    10  Foundation                          0x000000010c7db726 encodeInvocationArguments + 462  
    11  Foundation                          0x000000010c7e5af1 -[NSXPCEncoder encodeInvocation:] + 337  
    12  Foundation                          0x000000010c7e5974 -[NSXPCEncoder _encodeObject:] + 628  
    13  Foundation                          0x000000010c932143 -[NSXPCConnection _sendInvocation:withProxy:remoteInterface:withErrorHandler:timeout:userInfo:] + 2478  
    14  Foundation                          0x000000010c93176c -[NSXPCConnection _sendInvocation:withProxy:remoteInterface:withErrorHandler:] + 32  
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e99cf4f ___forwarding___ + 495  
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e99ccd8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120  
    17  AddressBookUI                       0x000000010be542cc -[CNContactPickerExtensionHostContext setupWithOptions:readyBlock:] + 284  
    18  AddressBookUI                       0x000000010be53db4 -[CNContactPickerHostViewController setupWithOptions:readyBlock:] + 159  
    19  AddressBookUI                       0x000000010bd94930 -[CNContactPicker _setupViewController] + 1023  
    20  AddressBookUI                       0x000000010bd9450c -[CNContactPicker _setViewController:] + 322  
    21  AddressBookUI                       0x000000010bd94d4e __41-[CNContactPicker _prepareViewController]_block_invoke112 + 64  
    22  AddressBookUI                       0x000000010be53c76 __55+[CNContactPickerHostViewController getViewController:]_block_invoke + 378  
    23  UIKit                               0x000000010d608ed2 __117-[NSExtension(UIViewControllerAdditions) instantiateViewControllerWithInputItems:listenerEndpoint:connectionHandler:]_block_invoke_3 + 160  
    24  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010ef24186 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12  
    25  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010ef43614 _dispatch_client_callout + 8  
    26  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010ef2ba1c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1664  
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e9a71f9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9  
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e968dcb __CFRunLoopRun + 2043  
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e968366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470  
    30  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000110523a3e GSEventRunModal + 161  
    31  UIKit                               0x000000010d142900 UIApplicationMain + 1282  
    32  QwerTyuiop                          0x000000010a15f894 main + 100  
    33  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010ef78145 start + 1  
    34  ???                                 0x0000000000000007 0x0 + 7  
)  
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Testing on iPhone 5s 8.3 simulator. Anyone had similar issue?

Comment: Can you include the full program stack from the error?

Comment: @ckhan Added. Hope that's what you mean.

Comment: You can only use 'string' predicates, e.g. constructed with `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:]` in the AddressBookUI framework. I have the same thing as you myself a couple of weeks ago and it doesn't work. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26200502/predicatewithblock-as-the-predicate-for-abpeoplepicker-predicateforenablingperso) is someone with the same problem, but alas no solution.

Comment: With XPC on the stack, it looks like CNContactPicker works by communicating with an external process, which would explain why it needs to pickle (encode) your objects (and then correctly refuses to do so when the data in said object is code (a block)).